# Node.js server that accepts POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I'm trying to allow javascript to communicate with a Node.js server.

**POST request (web browser)**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "text=stuff";
http.open("POST", "http://someurl.net:8080", true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

alert(http.onreadystatechange);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}

http.send(params);
```

Right now the Node.js server code looks like this. Before it was used for GET requests. I'm not sure how to make it work with POST requests.

**Server (Node.js)**

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;

  if (queryData.text) {
    convert('engfemale1', queryData.text, response);
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3', 
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="tts.mp3"'
    });
  } 
  else {
    response.end('No text to convert.');
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You'd have to use `data`/`end` events of `request`, I believe. This works for me: http://pastebin.com/6aKv7WHJ. Not sure if that's the real way to do it, though.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the javascript POST request. It's not receiving data on the node.js server when I try to make a request.

Comment: Although I think that's the correct code for the node file. The javascript is the problem

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The following code shows how to read values from an HTML form. As @pimvdb said you need to use the request.on('data'...) to capture the contents of the body.

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.dir(request.param)

  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log('POST')
    var body = ''
    request.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data
      console.log('Partial body: ' + body)
    })
    request.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Body: ' + body)
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
      response.end('post received')
    })
  } else {
    console.log('GET')
    var html = `
            <html>
                <body>
                    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name: 
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>`
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    response.end(html)
  }
})

const port = 3000
const host = '127.0.0.1'
server.listen(port, host)
console.log(`Listening at http://${host}:${port}`)
```

If you use something like [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) and [Bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) then it would look like this since Express will handle the request.body concatenation

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  console.log('GET /')
  const html = `
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name: 
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>`
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
  response.end(html)
})

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
  console.log('POST /')
  console.dir(request.body)
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
  response.end('thanks')
})

const port = 3000
app.listen(port)
console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
```

Comment: The problem I'm having now though is that the javascript can't even make a request. When I try to make a request the node.js file does nothing.

Comment: That might have been because the previous code that I included didn't send anything response for the POST request (It only displayed on server that we received a POST.) I've updated the code to actually respond in the POST and that takes care of it. I also included the HTML that I used to test it (which includes your JavaScript code)

Comment: Where does the (err) check go? As a variable before req & res, then inform user via console.error(err.stack); otherwise a very complete example, I learnt a lot, kudos.

Comment: I realize this answer is old but I just wanted to point out that BodyParser now has to be installed separately

Comment: seems weird to have the form action assume localhost, when it could just be /

Answer (score 15):

Receive POST and GET request in nodejs :

1).Server

```
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer ( function(request,response){
    
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text\plain"});
    if(request.method == "GET")
        {
            response.end("received GET request.")
        }
    else if(request.method == "POST")
        {
            response.end("received POST request.");
        }
    else
        {
            response.end("Undefined request .");
        }
    });

    server.listen(8000);
    console.log("Server running on port 8000");
```

2). Client :

```
    var http = require('http');

    var option = {
       hostname : "localhost" ,
       port : 8000 ,
       method : "POST",
       path : "/"
    } 

    var request = http.request(option , function(resp){
       resp.on("data",function(chunck){
           console.log(chunck.toString());
       }) 
    })
    request.end();
```