# Submit/POST form data in JSON via ajax and jQuery to a Node.js webserver

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, post

This must be a simple question and I'm failing to see where is the error, so after reading and trying a lot of things and no advances, I surrender to ask for help!

**HTML**

```
...
<form id="FichaCadastral" method="POST">
  <input id="CPF" type="text">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
...
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  $('#FichaCadastral').on('submit', function (e) {
    var opa = {id: 3}; //Simple test data

    $.ajax({
      url: $(location).attr('pathname'), //I just want to know what webpage posted data
      method: 'POST',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(opa),
      processData: false,
      dataType: 'json', 
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }); //No success/done/fail callbacks for now, I'm focusing on this problem first

    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

**Node.js**

```
...
server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function (request, response) {
  if (request.method === 'POST') console.log(request.body); //shows 'undefined' in node-dev console
});
```

I don't know in which code above is the error, because I'm new in all of them.

Comment: Where do you reference the JavaScript? Some part of the HTML that wasn't included?

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12007627/3412775

Comment: @Tomty yes, I referenced in the head jQuery and page-specific js. Thanks for the link! It helped me a lot, there are a lot of similar questions but none that had a complete answer like that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, node does not process entity bodies (the POST data).  Rather, the raw bytes are emitted as `data` events.  You are responsible for parsing the request stream.

I'd recommend just using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware on your server.

---

Also,

```
url: location.pathname
```

`location` is a regular JavaScript object.  There is no need to wrap it in jQuery.

Comment: thanks. I'm not using Express or body-parser to learn how everything works, but sure, it would be a lot more easy. About jQuery, don't remember why I did it this way, any would do.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a complete answer without using Express or body-parser, here's the new code that I'm using and its working:

**Node.js**

```
...
server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function (request, response) {
  ...
  var data = '';
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  request.on('end', function () {
    if (data) {  //data shows '{"id":3}' in node-dev console
      if (request.method === 'POST') response = sPOSTResponse(request, data, response);
      //calls a method for controling POST requests with data captured
    };
  });
});
```