# How to save a FormData image file locally with "fs" in Node

Tags: node.js, image, express, file-upload, fs

I have a React front-end that allows user to send an image using `FormData()` to the node backend.

In the `Express` backend's controller, I am using `multer` as a middleware to grab the image into the `files` variable:

```
  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/image`, multerUpload.array("filesToUpload[]"), this.saveImage);
  }
```

In the backend's service, I am trying to save `files[0]` into the `uploads` folder:

```
  public saveImage(files: any) {
    console.log("OtherServiceLocal saveImage - files :");
    console.log(files[0]); // see screenshot at bottom for output

    let localPath = fs.createWriteStream("./uploads/image.png");

    files[0].buffer.pipe(localPath);
  }
```

But I am getting the error:
[image]

I tried piping `file[0]` and `file[0].buffer` to no avail, and I had difficulty understanding how to transform it into a stream even after some research.

This is the outputs for `console.log(files[0]);`

```
{
  fieldname: 'filesToUpload[]',
  originalname: 'Screen Shot 2021-09-08 at 3.42.48 PM.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 03 85 00 00 02 c5 08 06 00 00 00 74 ff 46 78 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 62 ... 249405 more bytes>,
  size: 249455
}
```

Please note that I am aware that you can use multer's `upload` method to save the image as a middleware directly in the router, but I can't to do this due to some requirement of my app.

Thanks,

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477497/node-js-native-file-upload-form) it may helps

Answer (score 1):

`file[0].buffer` is an instance of Buffer.
So you can use `fs.writeFile` directly

```
fs.writeFile("./uploads/image.png", file[0].buffer, (err) => {
    console.error(error)
})
```