# Can't get req.body with client fetch() and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have simple app.js for Node.js under `localhost:3000`

**app.js:**

```
let http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    let response;
    if(~req.url.indexOf('post')) {
        response = req.body.content;
    } else {
        response = '<script src="http://localhost/fetch.js"></script>';
    }
    res.end(response);
}).listen(3000);
```

The file `fetch.js` is placed on my another local server and is successfully enqueued to the page

**fetch.js:**

```
read('http://localhost:3000/?post').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
async function read(url) {    
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            content: 'Text'
        })
    });
    return response.text();
}
```

So I render HTML with fetch.js which then send POST request to the same page, but with a query `?post`

However, when I run `node app.js` I get the error

> Can not read property 'content' of undefined

So I don't get `req.body`

Why and how to resolve?

Comment: if ~req.url…? what do you expect this to do?

Comment: If `req.url` contains `'post'`. This condition is working, so is not a problem

Comment: Is really req.body empty? Isn't it string, that has to be JSON.parsed?
Pretty nice post about your code: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006417/node-js-server-that-accepts-post-requests

Comment: this would be `if (req.url…)` as opposed to `if (~req.url…)`. ~ is the arithmetic `NOT` operator, i don’t see the use here. it may, however, negate your intended logic

Comment: @Psi https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/

Comment: @stckvrw could you please `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @Psi `~` is commonly used with `indexOf` as it returns `-1` when no elements are found. `~ -1` becomes `0`

Comment: @GrafiCode if I add `console.log(req.body)` I get `undefined`

Comment: i think you are missing parser for your http server, there is no body because you actually didn't parse the body. check this https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-parse-post-request-in-node-js-without-expressjs-body-parser/

Comment: @Ali with your code I receive `parseJson is not a function`

Comment: @stckvrw sorry, i updated the post. you may use it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are missing parser for your http server, there is no body because you actually didn't parse the body.

assemble the chunks like below then parse it as the header sais.

this is my work for myself

```
private parseBody(req: IncomingMessage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks: any[] = []

      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk)
      })

      req.on("end", () => {
        const data = Buffer.concat(chunks)

        switch (req.headers["content-type"]) {
          case "application/json":
            resolve(this.parseJson(data.toString()))
            break

          case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
            resolve(this.parseUrlEncoded(data.toString()))
            break

          default:
            resolve({})
        }
      })
    })
```

http server is very abstract and doesn't support anything basicly, i suggest using express or fastify.

working example: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-parse-post-request-in-node-js-without-expressjs-body-parser/

#### update

this is the class im using

http.resolver.ts

```
 private parseJson(data: string) {
    return JSON.parse(data)
  }

  private parseUrlEncoded(data: string) {
    const parsedData = new URLSearchParams(data)

    const dataObj: any = {}

    for (var pair of parsedData.entries()) {
      dataObj[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    }

    return dataObj
  }

  private parseBody(req: IncomingMessage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks: any[] = []

      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk)
      })

      req.on("end", () => {
        const data = Buffer.concat(chunks)

        switch (req.headers["content-type"]) {
          case "application/json":
            resolve(this.parseJson(data.toString()))
            break

          case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
            resolve(this.parseUrlEncoded(data.toString()))
            break

          default:
            resolve(parse(req.url ?? "/", true).query)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

you may use await behind the parseBody function after

Comment: Yes, that's just after mine) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to ***@Fide***. The link he posted has the answer:

```
let http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(~req.url.indexOf('post')) {
        let body;
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            body = data;
        })
        req.on('end', function() {
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(body);
        })
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('<script src="http://localhost/fetch.js"></script>');
    }
}).listen(3000);
```